# Show that $|x|=\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{4}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos\left((2k+1)x\right)}{(2k+1)^2}$

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, summation-method

The objective is to find the Fourier series for $|x|$ in the range $-\pi \le x \lt \pi$ so I started by finding the Fourier coefficients:

$$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x=-\pi}^{\pi}|x|\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x=0}^{\pi}x\mathrm{d}x=\pi$$

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x=-\pi}^{\pi}|x|\cos(nx)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x=0}^{\pi}x\cos(nx)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2\left((-1)^n-1\right)}{\pi n^2}$$

Then using the general Fourier series expansion: $$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\left(a_n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{L}\right)+b_n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{L}\right)\right) \tag{1}$$
where $2L$ is the period of the function 
and noting that $f(x)=|x|$ is even so $b_n=0$ such that only the cosine terms contribute to the sum.
Insertion of $a_0$ and $a_n$ into $(1)$ yields
$$f(x) = |x| =\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left((-1)^n-1\right)\cos(nx)}{n^2}\tag{A}$$ I can tell you from [this](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090904165050AAN43Qt) that $(\mathrm{A})$ is correct and I just need to show it is equal to $$\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{4}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos\left((2k+1)x\right)}{(2k+1)^2}\tag{B}$$ where $k$ is an integer, but I don't know how to. The calculation [here](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090904165050AAN43Qt) doesn't show the steps to get from $(\mathrm{A})$ to $(\mathrm{B})$. Could someone please show me these steps to complete the proof?

Thank you.

Comment: You might consider replacing every `\cfrac` by `\frac`.

Comment: @Did I'm sorry I don't follow your logic

Comment: @Did Okay it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left((-1)^n-1\right)\cos(nx)}{n^2}&=\sum_{n \text{ is odd}}\frac{\left((-1)^n-1\right)\cos(nx)}{n^2}+\sum_{n \text{ is even}}\frac{\left((-1)^n-1\right)\cos(nx)}{n^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left((-1)^{2n-1}-1\right)\cos((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left((-1)^{2n}-1\right)\cos((2n)x)}{(2n)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1-1\right)\cos((2n+1)x)}{(2n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(1-1\right)\cos((2n)x)}{(2n)^2}\\
&=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos((2n+1)x)}{(2n+1)^2}+0\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood everything you wrote apart from the part where you changed from $\cfrac{\cos((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2}$ to $\cfrac{\cos((2n+1)x)}{(2n+1)^2}$. In other words, why did $2n-1$ change to $2n+1$?

Comment: This is a change of variable. In general $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(n)=\sum_{n'=0}^{\infty}g(n')$ where $n'=n-1$. For example $\sum_{n=1}^{10}(n-1)^2=0^2+1^2+2^2+...+9^2=\sum_{n=0}^{9}n^2$. I hope this made the issue clear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: What is $(-1)^n-1$ when $n$ is even?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its zero for all even n, I have taken another look at it and I still don't know where to go from here.

Comment: @BLAZE Delete all even terms, and then change the index for summation.